# What tools can I use to create simple editable documentation pages with NodeJS and AngularJS app?

Tags: cms, node.js, wysiwyg, angularjs, documentation-generator

I'm developing a website that will, in addition to other pages and functionality, have a documentations section with navigation and search capabilities. I want to make it easily editable with CRUD operations for site admins. So site admins can, after logging in, create, delete, and edit pages.

I'm building the site using NodeJS and AngularJS.

I've look at NodeJS- and AngularJS-based CMS but they all have their own themes -- I want to be able to use my existing design patterns.

I've also looked at WYSIWYG editors, which look to be the most promising, but it looks like I'll have to implement my own CRUD operations.

What tools can I use to accomplish this? How do other sites create their documentation pages, such as:

- https://instagram.com/developer/
- https://stripe.com/docs/api#intro

Comment: Something like [Melkor](https://github.com/hiddentao/melkor)?